# How to test all ccavenue apis?

Tags: api, jsp, payment-gateway, ccavenue

**I have jsp_kit for integration cc-avenue.**

> i want to test all API(services) one by one(using postman) explicitly.
>
> How can i test?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot.The request should be made from a url.To set up a test url contact ccavenue.If you want to know all details how to set up then I have a blog post written.The implementation is made using asp.net mvc.Check it [here](https://srimansaswat.wordpress.com/2016/11/26/how-to-integrate-ccavenue-payment-gateway-in-asp-net-mvc/)